# Laravel: Calling PHPUnit without specifying the full path

Tags: laravel, phpunit

With Laravel 5, when you call `PHPUnit` from terminal, your'll type in something like...

`./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/TestClassName`

I've been searching for how to omit `./vendor/bin/`, so that you can call the test class above in the following way.

`phpunit tests/Unit/TestClassName`

Would it be possible to do stuff like this?

(The purpose is to use [a package of Sublime Text](https://github.com/adamwathan/sublime-phpunit).)

Comment: add it to your `$PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add `./vendor/bin/` to your $PATH.

alternatively, alias it in your bash profile.